# Cores no cmd usando Python?

Tags: python, cmd

Galera estou fazendo um jogo para faculdade e resolvi colocar umas cores no código para ficar bonitinho. Queria saber como faço para deixar as cores das strings aparentes no cmd do windows. Eu tentei utilizar o sistema Ascii mas não funcionou, segue abaixo um exemplo direto do código:

```
def menu():
print('\033[1;33mEntrando na configuração\033[1;33m')
select_rodadas()
select_player()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As duas ultimas linhas do cmd deveriam ficar da cor amarela ou laranja. Como faço para o cmd reconhecer as cores?

Comment: Sugiro consultar essa postagem [SO/en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-terminal-in-python/3332860#3332860)

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo usar o módulo [Colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama).

Exemplo de código para Python 3:

```py
from colorama import Fore, Style

print(f'{Fore.YELLOW}Entrando na configuracao{Style.RESET_ALL}')
```

Exemplo de código para Python 2:

```py
from colorama import Fore, Style

print '{}Entrando na configuracao{}'.format(Fore.RED, Style.RESET_ALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para aparecer no CMD do windows depois de copilado, precisa fazer uma correção do win10 e win7, encontrei a melhor correção nesse [link](https://www.clubedohardware.com.br/forums/topic/1418292-cores-do-python-no-windows/) adicionar um caso no regedit.

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console /v VirtualTerminalLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001 /f
```

No meu win10 tudo funcionou.